# How to stop datatable RowFilter dynamically updating

Tags: c#, datagridview, rowfilter

I have a datatable that i am filtering with this `rowfilter`:

```
        requestsTableAdapter.Fill(iTSTDataSet.Requests);

        DataTable adt = iTSTDataSet.Requests;
        var adv = new DataView(adt);
        adv.RowFilter = "Closed = " + false;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = adv;
```

It works perfectly and filters the `datatable` and only shows rows where `closed = false`.

The issue is, when i click on the checkbox and set another row to closed, that row will disapear from the `datagridview` automaticaly.

[image]

I dont want it to, i want it to update the view when i click a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just defer adding the row filter on the `dataView` until you've clicked the button? That should allow you to check the boxes to show the status but stop the rows disappearing until you want them to.

It would mean that you'd need to make the `dataView` accessible from wherever the command comes from, but is that too much of an issue?

### Edit

You can get the original dataTable minus closed items using a data table select at the start:
`iTSTDataSet.Requests.Select("Closed = false")`

and then apply the row filter on button press

Comment: No becuase the rowfilter applies when the program loads. I dont want to see closed tickets every time the program loads.

Comment: What about getting the original dataTable using a data table select at the start `iTSTDataSet.Requests.Select("Closed = false")` and then applying the further filter on button press?

Comment: perfect does exactly what i need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have there a filter that shows only rows that are not closed (Where closed = false) so you might just want to filter by "Closed" then choose Ascending or Descending order, one of those might be the right solution